# deleting a text label from image imagej

Tags: macros, imagej

I wrote a simple macro that results in inserting a text using function

`drawString(text, xposition, yposition);`

Is there a way to delete the text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`drawString` macro function](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#drawString) will irreversibly add the text into the pixel data of the image.

To add text as an overlay instead, use [`Overlay.drawString("text", x, y)`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#Overlay.drawString) (see [this example](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/macros/examples/OverlayDrawStringDemo.txt)). You can then remove the text by [hiding or removing the overlay](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Hide-Overlay).